# Inconsistent swift behavior

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift.

I have following code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let var1: Double = 0.0
let var2: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let someObject = TestViewController(x: 20, total: 30, taxPact: 40, subtotal: 50)
    var x = 1 + 1.0 /* COMPILER IS FINE WITH ADDING INT AND DOUBLE */
    print("sum is \(var1 + var2)") /* COMPILER COMPLAINS HERE BINARY OPERATOR + CANNOT BE APPLIED */
}
```

Why do we see such inconsistent behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is unrelated to string interpolation, this

```
let var1: Double = 0.0
let var2: Int = 0
var x = var1 + var2 // error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int'
```

does not compile either, and the reason is that there is no `+`
operator which adds an `Int` to a `Double` and
Swift does not implicitly convert types. You have to convert explicitly,
e.g.

```
var x = var1 + Double(var2)
print("sum is \(var1 + Double(var2))")
```

Your other statement

```
var x = 1 + 1.0
```

compiles because both `Int` and `Double` (and some more types)
conform to the `IntegerLiteralConvertible` protocol,
so the *literal* `1` can be both a `Int` literal
and a `Double` literal. Here the compiler chooses `1` to be a
`Double` because that is the only choice for which a suitable
`+` operator exists.

Comment: Although not perfect (may need to be slightly edited for Swift 2), there is a library made by github user seivan that extends the operators to work across numerical types : https://github.com/seivan/ScalarArithmetic